Error during wrapup: unused argument (grayscale = FALSE)
I experimented with keras and CNN in R and this code used to work just fine until yesterday. Since then I get the following error:
Error in (function (path, color_mode = "rgb", target_size = NULL, interpolation = "nearest",  : unused argument (grayscale = FALSE)
Called from: do.call(keras$preprocessing$image$load_img, args)
Browse[1]> test_data <- prepare_data(test_dir)
Error during wrapup: unused argument (grayscale = FALSE)
Error: no more error handlers available (recursive errors?); invoking 'abort' restart
Browse[1]> 

This is my code:
library(keras)


# Seed für Reprouzierbarkeit
set.seed(42)


# Pfad zu training und testing datensatz
train_dir <- "path/training"
test_dir <- "path/testing"


# Zielgröße für Bilder festlegen, Channel = 3 für rgb
img_width <- 150
img_height <- 150
channels <- 3


# Preprocessing der Bilder
preprocess_image <- function(image_path) {
  image <- image_load(image_path, target_size = c(img_width, img_height))
  image <- image_to_array(image) / 255
  image <- array_reshape(image, c(1, img_width, img_height, channels))
  return(image)
}


# Daten vorbereiten
prepare_data <- function(directory) {
  categories <- list.files(directory, full.names = TRUE)
  images <- lapply(categories, function(cat) list.files(cat, full.names = TRUE, pattern = "\\.jpg$", recursive = TRUE))
  labels <- rep(seq_along(categories) - 1, sapply(images, length))
  images <- unlist(images, recursive = FALSE)
  x <- lapply(images, preprocess_image)
  y <- as.numeric(factor(labels)) - 1
  return(list(x = array_reshape(do.call(c, x), c(length(images), img_width, img_height, channels)), y = y))
}


# prepare_data Funktion für Trainings- & Tesdaten aufrufen
train_data <- prepare_data(train_dir)
test_data <- prepare_data(test_dir)


# Anzahl der Kategorien der Trainings- & Testdaten kontrolieren
table(train_data$y)
table(test_data$y)


# CNN Modell erstellen
model <- keras_model_sequential() %>%
  layer_conv_2d(filters = 32, kernel_size = c(4, 4), activation = "relu", input_shape = c(img_width, img_height, channels)) %>%
  layer_max_pooling_2d(pool_size = c(2, 2)) %>%
  layer_conv_2d(filters = 64, kernel_size = c(4, 4), activation = "relu") %>%
  layer_max_pooling_2d(pool_size = c(2, 2)) %>%
  layer_conv_2d(filters = 128, kernel_size = c(4, 4), activation = "relu") %>%
  layer_max_pooling_2d(pool_size = c(2, 2)) %>%
  layer_conv_2d(filters = 128, kernel_size = c(4, 4), activation = "relu") %>%
  layer_max_pooling_2d(pool_size = c(2, 2)) %>%
  layer_flatten() %>%
  layer_dense(units = 512, activation = "relu") %>%
  layer_dropout(rate = 0.5) %>% # um Overfitting zu minimieren --> zufällig 50% der Filter ausschalten
  layer_dense(units = 4, activation = "softmax")


# Modell compilen
model %>% compile(
  loss = "sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
  optimizer = optimizer_rmsprop(lr = 1e-4),
  metrics = c("accuracy")
)



# Modell trainieren
history <- model %>% fit(
  train_data$x, train_data$y,
  epochs = 11,
  batch_size = 20, # so viele Bilder werden verarbeitet bevor Parameter des Modells angepasst werden
  validation_split = 0.1
)


# Auswertung des Modells für Testdaten
evaluation <- model %>% evaluate(test_data$x, test_data$y)


# Accuracy ausgeben
evaluation <- as.list(evaluation)
accuarcy <- cat("Test accuracy:", evaluation$acc * 100, "%\n")

I already searched the r documentation for the image_load function from keras and saw that the grayscale argument is deprecated. But since I don't use this argument, I can't imagine why this would resolve in this issue.
The code normally processes the images, creates and trains the model and then evaluates it. It worked fine and got an accuracy between 94% - 98% on testing data

keras3, not keras, is recommended for new code today. Do you get the same error with keras3?

@t-kalinowski Thank you so much! After some type issues the code works perfectly fine now. Didn't knew about keras3.
